# Passing Tuple to view, loop through results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, arraylist, tuples

I am passing a Tuple to my partial view from my actionresult. I dont need to create a class because it will hold less than half a dozen items and will only be used once in the app. I had never heard of a Tuple before and it seemed liked the best way. Problem is how do I retrieve my results when I dont know how big the Tuple will be?

My code returns the error: "*foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'*"

Many sites explain this error "*if you want to use foreach on Tuple then you can inherit Tuple class and implement the child class with IEnumerable interface and provide definition for GetEnumerator method.*" to which I sit here and scratch my head as if I'm reading Urdu.

What would be the best way to refactor this to pass a List of List? Thanx in advance for your suggestions.

My Actionresult:

```
   List<Tuple<string, string>> mylist = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();


        string[] bits = stringvar.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string bit in bits)
        {
    ... //some string manipulation here

            mylist.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(string1, string2 ));                
        }

        ViewData["FolderPath"] = mylist;

        return PartialView("MyPartialView");
```

and my Partialview:

```
  <% if (ViewData["FolderPath"] != null) {

   var mystuff = ViewData["FolderPath"];

   foreach (Tuple<string, string> item in mystuff)
   {
       string one = item.Item1;
       string two = item.Item2;  

    ... // do something with my strings       

   }
}             

   %>
```

Comment: I don't see any problem to create class if it is used only once. Class will make your code much more readable and easy to support. Maybe that's my personal dislike of tuples with their item1, item2, itemN

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You're not alone, I'm with you..

Comment: but in MVC shouldnt I create a Model instead? if so, why create a whole Model for just this stupid but of code, if not, where exactly should I put the class? I could easily just pass the string to the view and split/loop through it there, but somehow that just doesnt seem right.

Comment: @user116923 what kind of strings you are passing? What is meaning of Item1 and Item2?

Comment: Agree with @SergeyBerezovskiy. You should try a class instead a tuple even if it is used only once. It's more readable and probably more... testable?;)

Comment: again, I dont disagree, I just have some questions about implementation and I'm trying to learn. Please see my earlier response.

Comment: Note: When you use tuples, you can use the nicer syntax `Tuple.Create(string1, string2)` instead of `new Tuple<string, string>(string1, string2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you write:

```
var mystuff = ViewData["FolderPath"];
```

you should try:

```
var mystuff = (List<Tuple<string, string>>)ViewData["FolderPath"];
```